# Inserting images to Excel with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, alasql

I'm currently exporting data to an xls file with **alasql** library, but I need to insert images to the same file.

I converted my image to base64 and added it to the JSON but shows pic related when exported:

[image: a busy cat]

I discarded the SheetJS library because this features are in the Pro Version (not free).

**Edit 1**

My current JSON object looks like this, as you can see the base64 is there (I was trying with a url too) :

[image: a busy cat]

Im creating my table with this **alsql** query, where I insert my JSON and the style :

```
 alasql('SELECT * INTO XLS("testo.xls",?) FROM ? as dato',[mystyle,$scope.datoXslx]);
```

Comment: Please add code demonstrating what you're trying to do so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Added a little code explanation in my **edit 1**